# vulkan validation layer issue

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am following this tutorial. https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers

for learn the validation layer

However, the validation layer does not print any messages.

If this works, the message in the image below should be printed.

[image]

When I run my program, nothing is output as shown below.
[image]

Below is the whole part of my code.

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
};

#ifdef NDEBUG
const bool enableValidationLayers = false;
#else
const bool enableValidationLayers = true;
#endif

VkResult CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pDebugMessenger) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDebugMessenger);
    }
    else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}

void DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        func(instance, debugMessenger, pAllocator);
    }
}

class HelloTriangleApplication {
public:
    void run() {
        initWindow();
        initVulkan();
        mainLoop();
        cleanup();
    }

private:
    GLFWwindow* window;

    VkInstance instance;
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger;

    void initWindow() {
        glfwInit();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    void initVulkan() {
        createInstance();
        setupDebugMessenger();
    }

    void mainLoop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    void cleanup() {
        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, debugMessenger, nullptr);
        }

        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwTerminate();
    }

    void createInstance() {
        if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
        }

        VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

        VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

        auto extensions = getRequiredExtensions();
        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

        VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugCreateInfo;
        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
            createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();

            populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(debugCreateInfo);
            createInfo.pNext = (VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT*)&debugCreateInfo;
        }
        else {
            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

            createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        }

        if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
        }
    }

    void populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT& createInfo) {
        createInfo = {};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
        createInfo.messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT;
        createInfo.messageType = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT;
        createInfo.pfnUserCallback = debugCallback;
    }

    void setupDebugMessenger() {
        if (!enableValidationLayers) return;

        VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT createInfo;
        populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(createInfo);

        if (CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, &createInfo, nullptr, &debugMessenger) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to set up debug messenger!");
        }
    }

    std::vector<const char*> getRequiredExtensions() {
        uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
        const char** glfwExtensions;
        glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

        std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);

        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            extensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);
        }

        return extensions;
    }

    bool checkValidationLayerSupport() {
        uint32_t layerCount;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

        for (const char* layerName : validationLayers) {
            bool layerFound = false;

            for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers) {
                if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
                    layerFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!layerFound) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity, VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* pCallbackData, void* pUserData) {
        std::cerr << "validation layer: " << pCallbackData->pMessage << std::endl;

        return VK_FALSE;
    }
};

int main() {
    HelloTriangleApplication app;

    try {
        app.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have tried a few things to solve the problem.

1. Make sure the Vulkan SDK is installed correctly.
   -> correct
   [image]

What else should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you're following says you'll get that message *if you run the program at a specific point*.  Specifically you get errors like that if you run the program before you've added the call to `DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT`.

If you properly cleanup the debug messenger before destroying the instance, there's no reason you'd get a validation message about not doing that.  If you go into your `cleanup` function and comment out this block:

```
if (enableValidationLayers) {
    DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, debugMessenger, nullptr);
}
```

Then you should see some kind of validation output when you shut down the application.

Also, don't rely on the messages being *exactly* like they are in the tutorial.  That can depend on the version of the Vulkan SDK and the validation layers that are installed on your system.  In my case I get this output:

[image]